# Tobacco content - Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

**Question statement:** A tobacco company claims that the amount of
nicotine in one of its cigarettes is a random variable with mean 2.2 mg and standard deviation 0.3 mg. However, the average nicotine content of 100 randomly chosen cigarettes was 3.1mg. Approximate the probability that the average would have been as high as or higher than 3.1 if the company’s claims were true.

**My attempt:**
Let $X$ be the average amount of nicotine in the cigarettes, measured in mg. If the claim of the company is true, then X has mean $2.2$ and variance $\dfrac{0.3^2}{100}$ or a standard deviation of $\dfrac{0.3}{10}=0.03.$ Thus, the probability requested is $$\mathbb{P}(X>3.1)=\mathbb{P}\left(\dfrac{X-2.2}{0.03}>\dfrac{3.1-2.2}{0.03}\right).$$
Using the Central Limit Theorem, the quantity can be approximated by $$1-\Phi(30) \approx 0.$$

Now, the solution gives the same answer, but the method is different. In particular, they divide by $\sqrt{0.03}$ rather than $0.03$ as I do. But why is this?

[Picture of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXMf9.png)

Thank you.

Comment: The given solution is wrong. The standardized random variable is $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$, where the standard deviation of an amount of nicotine in one of its cigarettes is $\sigma=0.3$.

Comment: Thanks again! So I guess the division should be by 0.03. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is very likely. You're welcome.